# QuickBooks (QBD) SyncActivityResponse SyncType attribute Values: Upload, Writeback difference

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using SyncActivity object to get the last sucessful opration on QuickBooks SalesReceipt, but in response I am getting multiple SalesReceipt with SyncType attribute  Values: Upload, Writeback.

Can anybody help me out with giving the diffrence in these values.

Sample response is as below,

```
    <SyncActivityResponses>
- <SyncActivityResponse>
  <SyncType>Upload</SyncType> 
  <StartSyncTMS>2013-07-23T03:20:07.0</StartSyncTMS> 
  <EndSyncTMS>2013-07-23T03:20:07.0</EndSyncTMS> 
  <EntityName>SalesReceipt</EntityName> 
  <EntityRowCount>1</EntityRowCount> 
  </SyncActivityResponse>
- <SyncActivityResponse>
  <SyncType>Writeback</SyncType> 
  <StartSyncTMS>2013-04-19T01:24:05.0</StartSyncTMS> 
  <EndSyncTMS>2013-08-19T02:23:08.0</EndSyncTMS> 
  <EntityName>SalesReceipt</EntityName> 
  <EntityRowCount>595</EntityRowCount> 
- </SyncActivityResponse>
</SyncActivityResponses>
```

As we are exporting SalesReceipt to cloud and then Sync Manager Sync SalesReceipt to QuickBooks.I need last successful Synced SalesReceipt date , which one I should pick   `<SyncType>Writeback</SyncType>` or `<SyncType>Upload</SyncType>` .

Thanks,

Reshma D.

Answer (score 1):

```
- <SyncActivityResponse>
  <SyncType>Upload</SyncType> 
  <StartSyncTMS>2013-07-23T03:20:07.0</StartSyncTMS> 
  <EndSyncTMS>2013-07-23T03:20:07.0</EndSyncTMS> 
  <EntityName>SalesReceipt</EntityName> 
  <EntityRowCount>1</EntityRowCount> 
  </SyncActivityResponse>
```

It suggests, you added data (SalesReceipt) *in QB Desktop* on 23rd July and synced with cloud.

**Upload** - [ Company file -> cloud ]

```
- <SyncActivityResponse>
  <SyncType>Writeback</SyncType> 
  <StartSyncTMS>2013-04-19T01:24:05.0</StartSyncTMS> 
  <EndSyncTMS>2013-08-19T02:23:08.0</EndSyncTMS> 
  <EntityName>SalesReceipt</EntityName> 
  <EntityRowCount>595</EntityRowCount> 
- </SyncActivityResponse>
```

You added some data(SalesReceipt) *using IDS API* on 19 Aug and synced with cloud. It first got synced with company file and then uploaded to cloud.

**Writeback** [IDS -> Company file -> Cloud ]

Thanks